# Rxjs operator, transform an array to Json format

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am grouping payloads with merge map, and to be able to separate the results, i want to have a series of Json (objects) as Arrays.
Like this: {Array1:[]}, Array2:[]}
I use the toArray() operator to get the payload as an Array, but i dont now (maybee map operator) how to put this array in an Object (Json).

```
const image$ = ref.getDownloadURL().pipe(toArray());
```

The result is: 
[ {...}, {...}, {...} ]
And what i want is:
{ objectName:[ {...}, {...}, {...} ] }

Thanks for your help.

Comment: just use `map()` I guess. Like `map(array => ({objectName: array }))`

Comment: how do you get the objectName? Would you have multiple different keys like this?

Comment: No i just want one object name like this:
 { objectName:[ {...}, {...}, {...} ] }

Comment: In that case, Martin's answer is the way to go

Comment: map(array => ({objectName: array })) This solution is working perfectly, so the code is:
const image$ = ref.getDownloadURL().pipe(toArray(), map(array => ({objectName: array })));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is :

```
const image$ = ref.getDownloadURL().pipe(toArray(), map(array => ({objectName: array })));
```